# Use old installable usb and lots of updates or a new installable usb?

Tags: system-installation

Several months ago I made a bootable usb to install linux 14.04 LTS on my pc. I installed it and have been keeping it up to date using software updater. I now have the opportunity of installing on another machine. Should I use the same install and a big software update or make a fresh bootable usb?

Comment: This you choice. It does not matter much.

Answer (score 0):

Use the existing USB to install  Ubuntu 14.04 and update Ubuntu 14.04 immediately after installing it to install the security updates. There will be less total megabytes to download that way.